# How to create an event listener that can push keycloak event logs to s3?

Tags: java, maven, amazon-s3, keycloak, maven-plugin

I have built an Event Listener SPI (Plugin) for Keycloak by referring https://dev.to/adwaitthattey/building-an-event-listener-spi-plugin-for-keycloak-2044.
By copying the generated JAR file to $KEYCLOAK_DIR/standalone/deployments/ and adding the event listener in Event Config I was able to see the login event logs in Keycloak console.

But I need a JAR file that can capture keycloak login events as well as push the logs to s3.

Thank you.